# Can't get ILMerge to build single-file console application that works

Tags: c#, ilmerge

I'm trying to create a single-file executable. The code is .Net-based and also relies on some additional libraries including SQLite.

When I compile the source code, all of the relevant files go into the Release directory, although the SQLite DLL (sqlite3.dll) goes into a sub-directory (x86). I think this happens because I'm using SQLite-raw and that "spits out" both x86 and x64 copies of the DLL.

My initial command line to try is:

```
ILMerge /out:GEDtoRH.all.exe GEDtoRH.exe *.dll /target:exe /targetplatform:"v4,C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2" /wildcards /log
```

This produces the following output that worries me:

```
AssemblyResolver: Assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime' is referencing assembly 'System.Runtime'.
        ...
        AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in framework directory.
AssemblyResolver: Unable to resolve reference. (It still might be found, e.g., in the GAC.)

AssemblyResolver: Assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime' is referencing assembly 'System.Threading.Tasks'.
        ...
        AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in framework directory.
AssemblyResolver: Unable to resolve reference. (It still might be found, e.g., in the GAC.)

AssemblyResolver: Assembly 'System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime' is referencing assembly 'System.IO'.
        ...
        AssemblyResolver: Did not find assembly in framework directory.
AssemblyResolver: Unable to resolve reference. (It still might be found, e.g., in the GAC.)

Location for referenced module 'sqlite3' is ''
```

1. Should I be concerned about the unresolved references? The reason I ask is because the finished executable doesn't work. It breaks with a null reference exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object) on this line:

`file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filename);`

The un-merged version of the executable works fine :( It isn't "filename" that is broken as I've tried adding some extra tests and it is fine.

2. Try as I might to add the sqlite3.dll to the list of things to ingest, if I try, ILMerge just complains with a "Could not load assembly" error.

Answer (score 1):

As SQLite is not a .NET library it doesn't contain any IL to be merged

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense :) Is there anything I can do to create a single executable that also contains the code from the SQLite dLL?